# The target of a finite morphism $f$ is a dense open in $S$, can you extend $f$ to have target $S$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be a quasi-compact open dense subscheme of a scheme $S$ and let $X \rightarrow U$ be a finite surjective morphism. Does there exist a finite morphism $Y \rightarrow S$ such that the $U$-scheme $Y_U$ is isomorphic to $X$?

If that helps, feel free to assume that all the schemes involved are Noetherian or that all the maps in question are of finite presentation.

Comment: Yes, for qcqs $S$; it is a consequence of Zariski's Main Theorem ("Nagata compactification for the quasi-finite case"). Namely, for qcqs $S$, a quasi-compact open subscheme $U \subset S$, and finite morphism $f:X \rightarrow U$, the composite map $X \rightarrow S$ is quasi-finite and separated. Thus, Deligne's version of Zariski's Main Theorem (EGA IV$_4$, 18.12.13) gives an $S$-finite $X'$ with $X$ open in $X'$ over $S$. We may arrange $X$ is schematically dense in $X'$, so $X$ is schematically dense in $X'_U$; but $X$ is also closed in $X'_U$ since $X$ is $U$-finite! Thus, $X = X'_U$.

Comment: A little more concretely: consider the sheaf of functions on $X$ that are integral over the subring of functions pulled back from $S$. Does the global $Spec$ of this sheaf of subrings give a $Y$?

Comment: @AllenKnutson: In the EGA proof of Zariski's Main Theorem integral closures certainly play an important role, but the question you pose has a negative answer because $X$ could be non-reduced or non-normal and even if everything were integral one has to handle the fact that integral closures of noetherian domains in finite extensions of their fraction field are generally not module-finite. (One of the reasons the proof of ZMT in EGA involves passage to finite type $\mathbf{Z}$-schemes is to ensure module-finiteness for certain normalizations, due to excellence considerations.)